# no me reconoce los checkboxes al enviarlos por POST

Tags: php, php7, php5

tengo el siguiente código, traigo los checkboxes dependiendo las personas que esten guardados en la BBDD (son personas para adjuntarlos a una Reunión), y las personas vienen de la base de datos sin problema, cada quien con su checkbox y su value es el id de la base de datos igualmente cada uno es diferente su ID ya al inspeccionarlo desde el navegador todo correcto

el problema esta que cuando, el checkbox esta dentro del arreglo me genera por ejemplo 10 personas de la BBDD y perfecto todo bien, pero al seleccionar por ejemplo 3, 5, las 10 personas en la pagina donde hago el ACTION miro que datos llegan y NADA es como que no seleccione NINGUNO

ahora bien, saco el checkbox del arreglo (obviamente me genera solo uno porque no esta dentro del arreglo lo marco y lo envio por POST y alli si me lo lee, que puede ester pasando!!!

```
                                        <?php
                                        try {
                                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personas";
                                            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
                                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                                            $error = $e->getMessage();
                                            echo $error;
                                        }
                                        while ($participante = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="icheck-danger d-inline">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $participante['Id_Persona']; ?>"><label><?php echo $participante['Nombres']; ?></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php  }  ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                      
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Espero haber entendido lo que requieres y que está pasando... Los ckeckboxes no debería llevar como valor (Value) el ID de la persona, más bien un valor booleano (Verdadero o falso) y así debería funcionar, con un ID no debería el sistema entender ese dato. Crea sino lo tienes un campo en la BD de tipo boolean.

Comment: pero porque fuera del while si lo lee, necesito el value para insertar ese ID a la tabla participantes haciendo referencia a ese Value

Comment: Fuera del while hay un solo resultado, quizás por eso, no lo sé... Tomará el primer ID que es uno (1) como verdadero.

Comment: Tienes que mostrarme las tablas y sus relaciones, así sería más fácil poder ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no vemos donde abres y cierras el formulario. Ni como recoges los valores, de todas formas los datos los estas enviando bien y en principio tendrias que poder recoger cada id de cada checkbox seleccionado.